# eclipe rap demo source code

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I was going through the eclipse RAP tutorials,examples and Demos.
From the official site I got some demo. Any idea how to get the
source codes for that demos? I tried to get through CVS access. But could not find the
demo source code. Request you to help on this.

Following is the site which is having demo.

[enter link description here](http://rap.eclipsesource.com/rapdemo/examples#input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it via git:

https://github.com/eclipse/rap/tree/master/bundles/org.eclipse.rap.examples and
https://github.com/eclipse/rap/tree/master/bundles/org.eclipse.rap.examples.pages

Comment: I could checkout the projects from the location which you gave. Thanks. But there are many compilation error. Could you ressolve the compile time errors? How did you do that?

Comment: I didn't build it. Probably you have conflicts with your target platform which is also RAP.